# How to find what one table have elements of second table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have 2 Tables, that related with third by one-to-many relation.
For example I have Table A, Table B and Table C.

Table A and B related with table C as many-to-one. So in Table C I have 2 fields like tableAId and tableBId. As a result I need to find a list which includes all Elements from table C which related with table A and compare them to all elements from table C which related with table B.

I tried do it with except, minus statements, but it works incorrect.

Here is what I try to do:

```
SELECT tableAId  FROM tableC 
except
select tableBId FROM tableC
```

***UPDATE***

Here is my 3 tables :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ga9Lk.png)

Comment: Have you tried something yet?  Also, please show some sample data in the way of a formatted table (each line indented by 4 space).  This will make your question more transparent.

Comment: would you understand the problem/question with the information provided? i guess not. so please add information like @TimBiegeleisen wrote

Comment: Most likely you'll have to do some joining between the three tables, and then maybe use `EXCEPT`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  If it possible, could you show me, how to do it.

Comment: Update your question with sample data for all three tables, and the output you expect.  Then anyone familiar with the SQL tag would be able to give you a query.

Comment: You also need to get clear in your head the difference between *rows* and *columns*. They are distinctly different concepts in SQL (as compared to e.g. a spreadsheet where they're interchangeable).

Comment: Your table structure is messed up. How have you defined relation between tableA and tableB ? Ideally, TableC should have `Id(int), OtherTableId(int), Description(varchar)` Then you can map tableC.Id with tableA/tableB through OtherTableId

Comment: "Related as many to many" is not clear. Neither is that whole paragraph. Just take the time to say exactly what you mean. Please read [ask] and [mcve]. PS Use text whenever possible. Like instead of that image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% following what you require but i think below is what you want

```
SELECT a.ID, b.ID
FROM TableA a
JOIN TableC c ON a.ID = c.TableCID
JOIN TableB b ON c.TableBID = b.ID
```